# Role of ALU in executing MOV instruction

Tags: alu

1.What is the role of ALU in executing instructions such as MOV, SET bit, Reset bit which doesn't require any computational feature of ALU?

2.Arithmetic part of ALU makes use of logic gate combination to implement arithematic operation, is it safe to say ALU is basically composed of logic gates?

Comment: It depends on the specific CPU design. Typically, either the ALU is not involved, or the ALU is set up to output one of the inputs.

Comment: re 2: *everything* in a digital computer can be represented as logic gates. (True random number generators excluded, but you can model these being a monkey that's been handed 20 espresso pralines and the task to randomly smash buttons attached to logic gates.)

Comment: @MarcusMüller monkeys smashing things have been shown to be very biased random event generators :) https://www.wired.com/2003/05/monkeys-dont-write-shakespeare

Comment: In some architecture the bit set/reset is implemented in the ALU with the and/or logic, so it's not true that it doesn't require computation.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on the ISA and implementation.

Your ALU may have a pass through op, or it may not. There are tricks like OR(0,X) to allow it to pass through if it does not.

Or there may be a bypass path around the ALU. In that case the ALU may have a different role such as calculating an address for the MOV.

Without knowing which CPU you are talking about this question cannot be answered.

Answer (score 2):

In an architecture that passes all operands through the ALU (typical for a microprocessor), a MOV instruction will simply pass the operand through unmodified on to the destination. It can be a trivial version of bitwise-OR with zero for example, or an explicit instruction all its own.

Likewise, bitwise manipulation instructions would use logic OR and AND to implement them, using logic in the ALU.

And yes, an ALU is ultimately composed of logic. For a glimpse into how this is done, there’s a famous TTL ALU chip called the **74LS181**, which in the 1970s formed the heart of many early minicomputers. The 74LS181 datasheet shows the gate-level logic implementation of this chip. It did arithmetic and logical operations on 4-bit operands, and could be extended by companion carry-lookahead logic. More about the '181 here: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn54ls181.pdf

Typical ALUs still do the same basic set of ops as that '181, one way or another.

Answer (score 0):

That *really* depend on the architecture of the microprocessor.

Some simpler architectures have no *proper* ALU but only features on the datapath. Multiscalar architectures can have *more* than one ALU, often specialized in functionality. Like a sum and a multiplication at the same time but a division keep them both occupied.

It could be argued that the bit set/reset is a logic operation (OR/AND in disguise) so these could be routed thru the ALU, too. Even a MOV could use it: for example in the PIC architecture a movf instruction will set the arithmetic flags.

As for the second part of the question, actually *everything* in the CPU is made of logic gates. Well, almost everything in a computer is, except dynamic memory (which is made mostly of capacitors and amplifiers and it's analog in nature)